# Type or namespace 'MVC' does not exist - error in VSTS build

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017, azure-pipelines

One of our class library project references System.Web.Mvc using the default .Net Framework assemblies. It compiles absolutely fine locally, but when trying to setup the build on VSTS Online, it throws the following error:

```
Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Should we be adding the DLL manually to be referenced ? or is there a way to tell VSTS to just use the .Net Framework DLLs ?

Comment: what version of mvc?  what version of .net?

Comment: MVC 4.0, .NET 4.5.
I have managed to find a workaround... instead of taking reference to Assemblies from system folders. I copied all the required DLLs (there were not many, about 8-10 - System.Web, System.Web.Mvc, few others) and copied them in a folder inside the solution and made that as part of the repo so VSTS could find the reference and build the solution without any issue.

Answer (score 1):

This DLL comes from the NuGet package [Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.mvc/) which means you are not correctly restoring your NuGet packages as part of your build.

[image]

Comment: all the other packages are restored correctly, somehow this is the one causing the issue.

Answer (score -1):

We had a similar issue where the code was building fine locally but not on Azure Devops.

We had a web app and a business logic project. The web app had a dependency to the business logic project. A class in the business logic project was referencing System.Web.Mvc, but the Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc Nuget package wasn't added to the business logic project.

All we had to do to resolve this was add the Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc Nuget package to the business logic project.
[Add Nuget reference to BusinessLogic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hadAE.png)

Comment: Please include the steps in your answer and not as a link to an image.